# laravel update from 5.1 to 5.2 composer update error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am trying to update laravel from 5.1 to 5.2 . I followed the instruction as according to [update doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0) but I am getting this error when running composer udpate:

`Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::bindShared() in /my_app/vendor/illuminate/html/HtmlSe
  rviceProvider.php on line 36`

I've looked up this issue and saw that people were getting this issue when updating to version 5.1 and saw that the method bindShared has been replaced with singleton(), but I don't want to mess with vendor files.
Here is my config/app.php providers and aliases arrays:

```
'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,

    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\ViewComposerServiceProvider::class,
    Laracasts\Flash\FlashServiceProvider::class,
    Baum\Providers\BaumServiceProvider::class

],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Class Aliases
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
| is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
| the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
|
*/

'aliases' => [

    'App'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
    'Artisan'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
    'Auth'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
    'Blade'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
    'Bus'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
    'Cache'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
    'Config'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
    'Cookie'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
    'Crypt'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
    'DB'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
    'Eloquent'  => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
    'Event'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
    'File'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
    'Hash'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
    'Input'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,
    'Inspiring' => Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring::class,
    'Lang'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
    'Log'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
    'Mail'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
    'Password'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
    'Queue'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
    'Redirect'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
    'Redis'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
    'Request'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
    'Response'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
    'Route'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
    'Schema'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
    'Session'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
    'Storage'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
    'URL'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
    'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
    'View'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
'Form'      => Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html'      => Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
'Carbon'    => 'Carbon\Carbon',
'Flash'     => Laracasts\Flash\Flash::class,

],
```

and here is my composer.json:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"repositories": [{
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://github.com/nWidart/Elasticquent"
    }],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.6@dev",
    "illuminate/html": "^5.0@dev",
    "laracasts/flash": "dev-master",
    "fairholm/elasticquent": "dev-feature/laravel-5",
    "baum/baum": "~1.1"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "~3.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "~3.0"

},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
}
```

any idea what I should do to fix this? I started with a 5.1 version install of laravel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `"illuminate/html"` component is no more supported by Laravel and is not compatible with the 5.2 version.

You can replace it with [laravelcollective/html](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html)

You have to:

- remove the reference of `"illuminate/html": "^5.0@dev"`, from `composer.json`
- add `"laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"` (or the version you want)
- run `composer update` to update the dependecies (this will remove your `"illuminate/html"` component and install the `"laravelcollective/html"` component

Now you have to replace your HTML service provider with:

```
 'providers' => [
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
  ],
```

and the facades:

```
  'aliases' => [
      'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
      'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
  ],
```

Comment: When I remove the illuminate/html reference and add laravelcollective i reference I get error: `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.` and then `Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.2.12` and later in the console output  `laravelcollective/html 5.1.x-dev requires illuminate/routing 5.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/routing[5.1.x-dev, v5.1.1, v5.1`

Comment: try `"laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*"`

Comment: Now laravelcollective downloaded 100% but now I got `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found in /my_app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php on line 648` .

Maybe this is a different issue now x(

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html instead of `illuminate/html` because it's now out of date in `Laravel 5.2`.