# Updating Laravel from 5.1 to 5.2 composer error

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-5

I am trying to update from laravel 5.1 to 5.2 and I am getting a composer error:

`Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider'
   not found in /my_app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Founda
  tion/Application.php on line 648`

This is after I followed the directions in the [laravel update docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0) and also removed `"illuminate/html": "^5.0@dev"` from my composer.json and added `"laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"` .

I did this because I was getting this error:

`Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::bindShared() in /my_app/vendor/illuminate/html/HtmlSe
  rviceProvider.php on line 36`

and was told that Illuminate htmlserivceprovider is deprecated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35085006/laravel-update-from-5-1-to-5-2-composer-update-error/35085790?noredirect=1#comment57894192_35085790).

So now I am getting the new error mentioned above when trying to run `composer update`.

Does someone know what is causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rolled back to working version before update, made changes in composer.json to remove illuminate/html and add laravelcollective/html and ran composer update then made changes for updating to 5.2 then ran composer update and used `"laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*"` instead of `"laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"` and now it works.